# Optimized Method that get comments count() of an article using doctrine2/Symfony

Tags: php, optimization, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I'am trying to find the best optimized way to get count of comments for each article

I have two entities: Article & Comment

the Comment Entity have a field :

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Easylist\ListmanagerBundle\Entity\Comment")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  private $comment;
```

So in my controller I want to Get All Article :

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
 $rep = $em->getRepository('ListmanagerBundle:Article');
 $all_Article = $rep->findAll();
```

I would like to have in the result of this query a field that contain the count of comments, like that :

```
array(
  "id"       =>  "1",
  "Title"    => "Just a test",
  "nbr_coms" => "320"
)
```

I thought to use a service but I found that services it's used in controller side not entities, like I thought to use the EntityManager into my Entity but it's not the Best way I think.

I'm looking for an optimized solution, because we are talking about a millions article that each one have a millions of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select just the fields you want to get a simple array:

```
public function countAll(){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT a.id, a.title, COUNT(c.id)
        FROM ListmanagerBundle:Article a
        JOIN a.comments c
        GROUP BY a.id
     ');
    return $query->getResult(); 
}
```

You might have to look at your mappings to make sure your `Article` has a `$comments` property of type `Collection`

Answer (score 1):

In a controller you can do `Article->getComments()->count()` or `Comments->count()` which are shortcuts to the `count()` php function.

In a twig template you can do a `{{ article.getComments|length }}` or `{{ comments|length }}` which use `mb_strlen()` or `count()`.

Both methods use native php functions and doesn't do additional db query.
Using this allows you to stick to the `findAll()` without the need to write a custom query.

Comment: Your solution sounds More optimized, but when i try  it out i got this error : Call to undefined method. and this it's look logical because i don't have any method named getComments() in my Article class.

Comment: As your Comment property is not pluralized you certainly have a getComment() method created in your Article Entity. But as an Article can have multiple comments, your property is supposed to be *Comments*